# How to return a queryset that is filtered by a class method in django 1.5

Tags: django, methods, filter, django-queryset

I am simplifying this dramatically just to make the question as clear as possible.

```
    class UploadedFile(model.Model)
        #actually inherits from a superclass s3file but not relevant

        objects = model.Manager

        def is_image(self):
            return self.content_type in ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif']
```

What I want is to be able to query my uploaded files with a filter that is something like `UploadedFile.objects.filter(is_image=True)` or `UploadedFile.objects.images.filter(...)` using custom Manager.

I know that I can create an UploadedFileManager, but I don't know how to do this so that it returns a queryset object and not a list. I dead end myself because list comprehensions `[x for x in all_uploads if x.is_image()]` are the only way I can think of to filter the queryset by that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't literally filter a queryset with a class method - queryset filters apply at the database level, and the database has no idea what your class method does. Your example can be implemented with `filter(content_type__in=('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'))`, which could easily be put into a custom manager, but if your real situation is too complex for such queries you have to either accept that you have to load objects into memory to do arbitrary Python on them or record something that the database can work with, like an `is_image` `BooleanField` that you would set when uploading.

Comment: This is an amazing answer. I think I can just build a complex query inside of a manager. I forgot how powerful those filters are and that there are the double underscore operators. Thanks so much.